# Why Lengths of Circuits of Graph be Coprime

Tags: statistics, graph-theory, information-theory

In Claude Shannon's paper,*A Mathematical Theory of Communication*, it states that

> 2. A closed series of lines in the graph with all arrows on the lines pointing in the same orientation will
>    be called a “circuit.” The “length” of a circuit is the number of lines in it. Thus in Fig. 5 series BEBES
>    is a circuit of length 5. The second property required is that the greatest common divisor of the lengths
>    of all circuits in the graph be one.

> If the first condition is satisfied but the second one violated by having the greatest common divisor equal
> to d > 1, the sequences have a certain type of periodic structure. The various sequences fall into d different
> classes which are statistically the same apart from a shift of the origin (i.e., which letter in the sequence is  called letter 1).

He gives an example:

> A simple example with d = 2 is the following: There are three possible letters a; b; c. Letter a is
> followed with either b or c with probabilities 1/
> 3 and 2/
> 3 respectively. Either b or c is always followed by letter
> a. Thus a typical sequence is
> abacacacabacababacac

However, I still don't understand how the lack of coprimality gives a shift. Could someone please elaborate further?

Thanks

Comment: The question in your title is poorly phrased. There is no guarantee that in general the lengths of circuits in a graph should be coprime. Shannon is saying that this property is one of the conditions required for the corresponding random process to be ergodic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are familiar with Markov chain terminology, another way of phrasing this is that if the chain is *$d$-periodic* with $d > 1$ (v.s. aperiodic with $d = 1$), the vertices of the graph can be partitioned into $d$ equivalence classes $C_0, C_1, \dots, C_{d-1}$ on which the chain moves around cyclically. That is, if $x \in C_k$, then $P(x, y) > 0$ only if $y \in C_{k + 1}$ (where the indices are taken modulo $d$). (For example, see Exercise 1.6 of Levin, Peres, Wilmer - Markov Chains and Mixing Times.)

In the example given, we have $C_0 = \{ a \}$ and $C_1 = \{ b, c \}$, so there are essentially the same number of elements from each class in the sequence (up to a shift).